# Xamarin.UITest: How To Verify Placeholder/Hint Text

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am writing a Xamarin.UITest for a cross-platform Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android app.

In my Xamarin.UITest, how do I verify the following properties:

- On Xamarin.Android, how can I verify the `Hint` property for an `EditText`?
- On Xamarin.iOS, how can I verify the `Placeholder` property for a `UITextField`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sample Code

```
string GetPlaceholderText(string entryAutomationId)
{
    if (app is AndroidApp)
    {
        return app.Query(x => x.Marked(entryAutomationId)?.Invoke("getHint"))?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
    }

    return app.Query(x => x.Marked(entryAutomationId)?.Invoke("placeholder"))?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
}
```

## Sample App

Here is the same code-snippet in [a sample app](https://github.com/brminnick/FaceOff) that demostrates how to accomplish this task in a cross-platform Xamarin.UITest:

https://github.com/brminnick/FaceOff/blob/master/UITests/Pages/WelcomePage.cs#L73

## Explaination

In Xamarin.UITest, to retrieve text from an Android `EditText` or a iOS `UITextField`, you must use the `Invoke` method to access the native [Java Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and native [ObjectiveC iOS API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield?language=objc). In our `Invoke` statements, we can take advantage of the native methods (`getHint()` on Android, and `placeholder` on iOS) to retrieve the string.

All tests were validated via [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud). The test report is [viewable here](https://testcloud.xamarin.com/test/faceoff_2169d2fc-f9cf-43c4-ae24-48db83e6d887/).